# Multiple values of k in the k-NN density estimator?

Tags: statistics, density-function

Even though the $k$-NN density estimator is already adaptive to the data, there is still a global value $k$ that controls the amount of smoothing in the entire space.
Is using multiple values of $k$ in different subsets of the data wrong? My intuition says that at the end of the day, the estimates mean "number of points per volume of space", and it wouldn't be a problem, but I can't seem to find out if that's actually OK, or if this has been done in the past.

I can see how that would not be a problem if used along a kernel function that would generate a proper PDF at the end. Not sure if this has any serious theoretical implications on the $k$-NN estimator.

Thank you!

Comment: The value of $k$ in the $k$NN density estimator is a parameter that is generally best set with a validation set:  Adjust $k$ to minimize an error on this validation set.

Comment: Thanks David. What if there are a combination of multiple values that minimize my error? Would that be OK?

Comment: Well... this requires a lot more discussion.  You should look up "bias-variance" tradeoff or "bias-variance" decomposition for more on that.  It is a subtle matter...